# Data manipulation and subsetting in R

Tags: r, subset

One of the columns in a dataframe tab1 is below:

```
PossessionPct
51
49
42.7
57.3
54
46
57.5
42.5
55.6
44.4
60.6
39.4
51
40.2
```

How do i extract from this column and classify the data into GOOD , MEDIUM and BAD based on the values?

Comment: Kind of impossible without any specifications for the factors.

Comment: @user3867198.  Please update with the format of expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
 dat <- structure(list(PossessionPct = c(51, 49, 42.7, 57.3, 54, 46, 
 57.5, 42.5, 55.6, 44.4, 60.6, 39.4, 51, 40.2)), .Names = "PossessionPct", row.names = c(NA, 
 -14L), class = "data.frame")

 dat$Group <- with(dat, cut(PossessionPct, breaks=c(-Inf,41,51,61),
                  labels=c("Good","Medium", "Bad")))

 split(dat,dat$Group)
```

Comment: @beginneR:
I have to segregate them into three seperate columns- Good Medium, Bad from the table.

Comment: @user3867198, 1. you should make that clear in the question, not in comments and 2. show the desired output for your sample data.

Comment: @user3867198.  If the lengths are of different sizes, it is better to split and keep it as `list`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (replace the values with your own thresholds for good/medium/bad.

```
with(tab1, ifelse(PossessionPct < 45, "Good", 
                  ifelse(PossessionPct > 50, "Bad", "Medium")))
```